# C - How to compare extended char sequence with function strcmp()?

Tags: c, char, strcmp

I need to compare whether string is equals or not to the following extended char sequence: "———" ( ALT + 0151 code repeated three times) that is in text file. How to do it with function strcmp() ?

A piece of the example text file (TSV):

Piracicaba  Av. Armando Salles de Oliveira  Lado par    13400-005   Centro
Piracicaba  Tv. Agostinho Frasson   ——— 13400-008   Centro
Piracicaba  Av. Armando Salles de Oliveira  Lado ímpar  13400-010   Centro

When I read the file and print the field is displayed "ùùù" on monitor.

The structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char cidade[50];
    char tipoLogradouro[20];
    char logradouro[50];
    char trecho[30];
    char cep[10];
    char bairro[50];
} Endereco;
```

The test is inside 'switch case' and the program is crashing in this part:

```
case 3:
      {
          if(strcmp(token, "———") == 0) // Change to "ùùù" and fails too. 
              strcpy(registro[i].trecho, NULL);
          else
              strcpy(registro[i].trecho, token);
          break;
      }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are you passing a `NULL` pointer to `strcpy`?

Comment: If you want to set an empty value into the string, use `strcpy(registro[i].trecho, "");` - using NULL will make it crash.

Comment: @tadman. Sorry. If value equals to "———" I want to assign "NULL" to struct field, but both (NULL or "") crashes the program. Any idea ?

Comment: @pelya. I've tried both (NULL or "") and any string and program crashes. Any idea ?

Comment: The reason you see ù instead of – is because your terminal's encoding is not set the same as whatever the source file is. This could be a Windows-1252 vs. ISO-8859-1 encoding incompatibility.

Comment: Other than this `strcpy`, that code should not crash. Which means it crashes because of something else. Probably your `i` variable goes beyond the `registro` array max size.

Comment: @pelya. YOU'RE RIGHT !!! I don't know how, but  a program line appears in another part of the code and even compiling did not give error, only in execution. I removed the line, replaced the "---" with the "\ x97 \ x97 \ x97" suggested by "bruceg" and the program is running perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often in C, you can only use 7-bit ASCII in a quoted string, so for upper ASCII you need to use the \x escape sequence with the hexadecimal code of the character.  So, in your case you can type: "\x97\x97\x97", since 97 is hex for 151 decimal.

```
case 3:
{
      if(strcmp(token, "\x97\x97\x97") == 0) 
          strcpy(registro[i].trecho, NULL);
      else
          strcpy(registro[i].trecho, token);
      break;
}
```

Comment: So, you are expecting '—' to be in the execution character set but not in the source character set? It is possible but much more likely than the source character set being ASCII.

Comment: @TomBlodget The problem could be any place from the editor on down the pipeline. It's always safest to use 7-bit ASCII in the source code file, but like you say, not always necessary.

Answer (score 0):

strcmp only fails on null, you can pretty much just do

```
if (strcmp(inputString,"———")==0){
   printf("Strings Equal\n")
} else{
   printf("Strings unequal")
}
```

If you're trying to just see if the string is in the larger string, strstr is the function your looking for not strcmp.

Comment: Thank you Ben. I will try it and post result later.

Comment: In case that you can't type your extended characters, you can always use  the \x escape sequence to insert a character with its hexadecimal code. So, in your case you can type: "\x97\x97\x97", since 97 is hex for 151 decimal.

Comment: @Ben. I did the changes but the program crashes... I change the string to "ùùù" and fails too.

Comment: @bruceg. I change the "———" with "\x97\x97\x97" but the program still crashes. (ALT + 151 is different from ALT + 0151 that's in the text file). Any idea ?

Comment: @bruceg. Your suggestion worked !!! I do not know how, but there was a line of code that was in another part of the program and only gave error at runtime. Now the program is running perfectly. Could you put your answer so I can mark it as correct? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` is for one thing and one thing **only**, and that is copying one string to another. If you give it `NULL`, that's not a string, and dereferencing a NULL pointer is going to cause a crash.

What you want is this:

```
 if (strcmp(token, "———") == 0)
    // Assign NULL pointer
    registro[i].trecho = NULL;
 else
    // Copy string to buffer
    strcpy(registro[i].trecho, token);
```

Remember `strcpy` is a very risky function to use as it assumes a lot of things about the destination buffer. If `trecho` isn't large enough to hold the `token` string, *including NULL terminator*, you get undefined behaviour. If `token` isn't properly NULL terminated you get undefined behaviour. There's a lot of ways this seemingly harmless code can go haywire.

Comment: I'm "newbie" in C language. I tried both (NULL or "") and "\x97\x97\x97" like bruceg told me and even any string and the program doesn't works.

Comment: Try not to say "doesn't work", that really doesn't communicate anything useful. Does it give you an error? Does it crash? Does it give unexpected results? I think you have an encoding issue here as well. Can you make a test file with `xxx` in it instead of this non-ASCII character? Unless the encoding in your program and in the file match this won't properly identify the token. You could always put some debugging in like `printf("Token: %02x\n", token[0]);` to see if the character is 0x97 as you expect or perhaps something else.

Comment: Remember that a debugger is a very useful tool for situations like this. Most have a way of inspecting the memory directly and showing it as hex.